# Need help using pyplot to plot multiple line charts in same plot for whitespace formatted data

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, indexing, iteration

```
28 121 106 112 134  
42 123 114 115 135  
56 130 118 124 138 
42 123 114 115 135
63 132 126 131 141(and 14 more rows....)
```

basically each row has 5 points that need to be plotted by line graph along equidistant x(say)
Even if i plot say 5 rows it decent enough. For now this has been my approach to tackle this but it displays a blank plot

```
for i in range(20):
print()
for j in range(5):
    print(int(mat[0].split()[j]),end='     ')
    plt.plot(j,int(mat[i].split()[j]),'r')
plt.show()
```

i checked and mat[i].split()[j] returns the proper no. for each row to be extracted but it is not getting plotted. I dont want to deal with dataframes now since the data is so simple.

Comment: Maybe try to add `plt.figure()` before the 3rd line

Comment: @Shir now it is showing 20 different windows all blank. Anyways I want all the plots to be in the same window.

Comment: Add it before the for loop. Each `plt.figure()` should open one window

Comment: A line between a single point makes little sense. Use e.g. `marker="o"` to plot a marker, at that position.